# Why isn't my google maps API reverse geocoder showing results?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to reverse geocode the latitude and longitude of my google maps and show the formatted address of the markers current position in a window when I have finished dragging the marker with dragend.

So far I have managed to get the window updating on dragend and displaying the longitude and latitude of it's current position but I am unable to display the address using reverse geocode.

I have followed the demo on the site and tried to implement it but can;t get it to work.

This is my code:

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function (event) {
        var point = marker.getPosition();
        map.panTo(point);
            document.getElementById("latitude").value = point.lat();
            document.getElementById("longitude").value = point.lng();
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.getPosition() + '</strong><br>' + address);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({latLng: event.latLng}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                }
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with

```
geocoder.geocode({latLng: point}, function(results, status) {
```

[`example`](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html)

Comment: Followed the example as attached, and added the autocomplete to it. thankyou